# Linux Mint 17 and windows on same laptop

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I have Linux mint and windows 7, I want to take out windows and add its space on c driver to mint.
How to do that ?

Comment: A little while ago I wrote this tutorial that explains how to do that properly. There is more to it than just deleting the partition. ==> http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/210983-dual-boot-delete-os.html#post1767171

Comment: @whs Unfortunately that tutorial doesn't cover the case where one OS is Linux :/

Comment: You are probably right if Grub is the bootloader.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need a linux live cd.
Boot from cd, and use gparted.
Delete with caution all windows partitions and resize/move your linux partitions as you wish.
Note that you may experience changes in uuid of your linux partitions so make note of each one of them.
After resizing/moving check if the uuids are the same. If so, you are ok.
If not, you must edit fstab (sudo gedit /etc/fstab) to correct the old with the new ones.
There is a small chance that you might need to reinstall grub afterwards.
Good luck!